# Djano how to create two different url parameter from same view for run two different if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I wrote an function for download csv file. I have two type of user doctor and patient. When any user visit  patient.html page he can download all patient data. I know I can write another function for downloads all doctor data when anyone visit doctor.html page  but I want to do it in same function. here is my code:

```
def exportcsv(request,slug=None):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv') 
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    all_patient = Patient.objects.all()
    all_doctor = Doctor.objects.all()
    if slug == None:
        if all_patient:
             response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=AllPatientData'+str(datetime.date.today())+'.csv'
             writer.writerow(['patient_id','patient_name','date_of_birth','age','phone','email','gender','country','state','city','zip_code','address'])     
             for i in all_patient:
                 writer.writerow([i.patient_id,i.patient_name,i.date_of_birth,i.age,i.phone,i.email,i.gender,i.country,i.state,i.city,i.zip_code,i.address])
        if all_doctor:
             response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=AllDoctorData'+str(datetime.date.today())+'.csv'
             writer.writerow(['docter_id_num','doctor_name','doctor_speciality','doctor_experience','date_joined'])     
             for i in all_doctor:
                 writer.writerow([i.docter_id_num,i.doctor_name,i.doctor_speciality,i.doctor_experience,i.date_joined])   
    
 
    
   

    return response
```

my **urls.py**

```
  path('export-csv-all-data/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-all-data'),
```

now it's downloading all patients and doctor data together. How to create  another ulr parameter for downloading all doctor ?

Comment: You can split the urls for patient and doctor

Comment: Giancarlo Ventura any idea how to split the urls for patient and doctor? can please show me an example ?

Comment: It can be accompleshed in different ways. if you want to reuse the function you can use url variables like ´path('export-csv-all-data/<str:person_type>',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-all-data'),

Comment: do I need to add any fields name `person_type` in my models?

Comment: then how to write the url somethings like this `href="{% url 'hospital:export-csv-all-doctor-data' str=object_list.person_type %}`

Comment: It depends on how you identify whether a person is a patient or a doctor.

Comment: let assume person will be doctor. then how to write the url  ? and do I need to include any fields in my models?